# Prolog: "chili" interpreter that expresses call stack and choice points

Tags: prolog, depth-first-search

The usual vanilla interpreter uses Prolog backtracking
itself to archive backtacking. I guess this is the reason 
why its called "vanilla":

```
solve(true).
solve((A,B)) :- solve(A), solve(B).
solve(H) :- clause(H, B), solve(B).
```

How about a "chili" interpreter, that doesn't use any
Prolog backtracking. Basically a predicate **first/?** to obtain
a first solution and a predicate **next/?** to obtain further solutions.

How would one go about it and realize such an interpreter in Prolog. The solution needs not be pure, could also use findall and cut. Although a purer solution could be also illustrative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is a slightly dumbed-down version of the interpreter given in Markus Triska's [A Couple of Meta-interpreters in Prolog](https://www.metalevel.at/acomip/) (part of *The Power of Prolog*) under *Reifying backtracking*. It is a bit more verbose and less efficient, but possibly a bit more immediately understandable than that code.

```
first(Goal, Answer, Choices) :-
    body_append(Goal, [], Goals),
    next([Goals-Goal], Answer, Choices).

next([Goals-Query|Choices0], Answer, Choices) :-
    next(Goals, Query, Answer, Choices0, Choices).

next([], Answer, Answer, Choices, Choices).
next([Goal|Goals0], Query, Answer, Choices0, Choices) :-
    findall(Goals-Query, clause_append(Goal, Goals0, Goals), Choices1),
    append(Choices1, Choices0, Choices2),
    next(Choices2, Answer, Choices).

clause_append(Goal, Goals0, Goals) :-
    clause(Goal, Body),
    body_append(Body, Goals0, Goals).

body_append((A, B), List0, List) :-
    !,
    body_append(B, List0, List1),
    body_append(A, List1, List).
body_append(true, List, List) :-
    !.
body_append(A, As, [A|As]).
```

The idea is that the Prolog engine state is represented as a list of disjunctive `Choices`, playing the role of a stack of choice points. Each choice is of the form `Goals-Query`, where `Goals` is a conjunctive list of goals still to be satisfied, i.e. the resolvent at that node of the SLD tree, and `Query` is an instance of the original query term whose variables have been instantiated according to the unifications made in the path leading up to that node.

If the resolvent of a choice becomes empty, it's `Query` instantiation is returned as an `Answer` and we continue with other choices. Note how when no clauses are found for a goal, i.e. it "fails", `Choices1` unifies with `[]` and we "backtrack" by proceeding through the remaining choices in `Choices0`. Also note that when there are no choices in the list, `next/3` fails.

An example session:

```
?- assertz(mem(X, [X|_])), assertz(mem(X, [_|Xs]) :- mem(X, Xs)).
true.

?- first(mem(X, [1, 2, 3]), A0, S0), next(S0, A1, S1), next(S1, A2, S2).
A0 = mem(1, [1, 2, 3]),
S0 = [[mem(_G507, [2, 3])]-mem(_G507, [1, 2, 3])],
A1 = mem(2, [1, 2, 3]),
S1 = [[mem(_G579, [3])]-mem(_G579, [1, 2, 3])],
A2 = mem(3, [1, 2, 3]),
S2 = [[mem(_G651, [])]-mem(_G651, [1, 2, 3])].
```

The problem with this approach is that `findall/3` does a lot of copying of the resolvent i.e. the remaining conjunction of goals to be proved in a disjunctive branch. I would love to see a more efficient solution where terms are copied and variables shared more cleverly.

Comment: Cool! Thank you very much. Looks pretty declarative in the sense that no cuts are used, except for body_append/3 cuts. But a findall/3 is also there. Oki Doki

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slight variation of reified backtracking, using difference lists.

```
first(G, [[]|L], R) :- !, first(G, L, R). %% choice point elimination
first([A], L, [A|L]) :- !.
first([H|T], L, R) :- findall(B, rule(H,B,T), [B|C]), !, first(B, [C|L], R).
first(_, L, R) :- next(L, R).

next([[B|C]|L], R) :- !, first(B, [C|L], R).
next([_|L], R) :- next(L, R).
```

Representation of rules and facts via difference lists looks for Peano arithmetic as follows:

```
rule(add(n,X,X),T,T).
rule(add(s(X),Y,s(Z)),[add(X,Y,Z)|T],T).

rule(mul(n,_,n),T,T).
rule(mul(s(X),Y,Z),[mul(X,Y,H),add(Y,H,Z)|T],T).
```

And you can run queries as follows:

```
?- first([mul(s(s(n)),s(s(s(n))),X),X],[],[X|L]).
X = s(s(s(s(s(s(n))))))
L = []

?- first([add(X,Y,s(s(s(n)))),X-Y],[],[X-Y|L]).
X = n
Y = s(s(s(n)))
L = [[[add(_A,_B,s(s(n))),s(_A)-_B]]]

?- first([add(X,Y,s(s(s(n)))),X-Y],[],[_|L]), next(L,[X-Y|R]).
L = [[[add(_A,_B,s(s(n))),s(_A)-_B]]],
X = s(n)
Y = s(s(n))
R = [[[add(_C,_D,s(n)),s(s(_C))-_D]]]
```